# Azure devops pass build parameters through Rest API

Tags: rest, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to pass a parameters through the build rest API using jira, but it doesn't override the parameter.

Pipeline:

```
parameters:
- name: "Testplan"
  type: string
  default: "NoPlanDefined"

stage: Test
  jobs:
  - job: Testing_And_Transfer
    - task: PowerShell@2
        displayName: "Testing API Call"
        inputs:
          targetType: 'filepath'
          filePath: './script/Jira.ps1'
          arguments: 
            -Jira_id ${{ parameters.Testplan }}
```

Jira.ps1 content:

```
Param(
    [string]$Jira_id = "no ID"
)
#-----------------------Jira API--------------------------
echo 'This is a test \n ID: '
echo $Jira_id
```

My rest command is setup like so:

> URL: [https://dev.azure.com/{My](https://dev.azure.com/%7BMy) corp}/MyHello/_apis/build/builds?api-version=6.0

Body:

```
{    
    "definition":  { 
        "id": 1 
        },
    "parameters": "{ \"Testplan\":\"Postman\" }"
}
```

- When using the trigger, the ps1 return **NoPlanDefined** as expected.
- When using a manual trigger and changing the parameter, the parameter
  get changed as expected.
- When trying to change the parameter through
  the Rest api, Testplan is empty instead of **Postman**.

I'm I doing something wrong with the REST API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because those are *not* parameters, despite the name used in the REST call. They are run-time variables, which behave differently and are available at a different scope than parameters.

There is a different API that allows you to specify `templateParameters`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run-pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1

Comment: At least at the time of this writing, the Build API in the OP will work also. But it's _very_ important to keep in mind that `templateParameters` is an object not a string. Hence in the payload the parameters attribute becomes `"parameters": { Testplan: "Postman" }`

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with PowerShell you can use the [AzurePipelinesPS](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzurePipelinesPS/4.0.7) module and the command below to pass parameters to pipelines when invoking them.

```
$id = '2' # your pipeline id
$templateParameters = @{
    Testplan = 'myTestPlan' # your parameter and value
}
Invoke-APPipeline -Instance https://dev.azure.com -Collection 'yourCollectionName' -Project 'yourProjectName' -ApiVersion '6.0-preview.1' -PipelineId $id -TemplateParameters $templateParameters
```

The module supports "sessions" to limit the number of required parameters. See the module's [github page](https://github.com/Dejulia489/AzurePipelinesPS) on how to create a session.