# Pass templateParameters to Azure DevOps using the Azure Devops .NET Client library

Tags: c#, .net, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to run a pipeline with the Azure DevOps Client for .NET and this works perfectly. But now I want to start passing parameters when starting a run. And it looks like I need to use the Pipelines/Runs API. But that one is not present in the .NET Library.

I'm currently doing this to start a build:

```cs
var client = connection.GetClientAsync<BuildHttpClient>();
        
var build = new Build
{
    Definition = buildDefinition,
    SourceBranch = branchName,
    Project = project
};

await client.QueueBuildAsync(build);
```

There is a `Parameters` property available, but according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69033901) on Stack Overflow, this is not the correct one.

I need to use the `templateParameters` on the `Pipelines/Runs` API. But... How do I call this API with the .NET client library? It doesn't seem to be present.

I am using the `Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient` NuGet package (which has a reference to `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client`). Do I really need to do a manual HTTP call to the Web API or am I missing something? Can I use the AzureDevops/TFS client to manually call the HTTP api?

#### Relevant things I did

- Looked for a `PipelinesHttpClient` or even a `RunsHttpClient`.
- Checked the `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.WebApi` NuGet package, but there is no documentation available for that.
- Looked at the [available samples on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-dotnet-samples/tree/main/ClientLibrary/Samples), but didn't find one that sets `templateParameters` or runs a HTTP call outside the library

Comment: I'm by no means at all an expert on this, but just found today that there is indeed a PipelinesHttpClient. I'm however not using the "Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient" NuGet package, but the "Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client" one. Its associated RunPipelineParameters type has a TemplateParameters property. I haven't tried using it, though.

Answer (score 3):

I've found out that the [Builds/Queue api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/queue?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) also accepts `templateParameters` in the request body. But this property is not available from the `Build` class in the .NET Client.

I have extended the `Build` class with the property I was missing.

```cs
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi;

namespace Models.AzureDevops

public class ExtendedBuild : Build
{
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public object? TemplateParameters { get; set; }
}
```

And I use this class to start a build, like this:

```cs
var client = connection.GetClientAsync<BuildHttpClient>();
        
var build = new ExtendedBuild 
{
    Definition = buildDefinition,
    SourceBranch = branchName,
    Project = project,
    TemplateParameters = new { MyParameter = "Yes it works!" }
};

await client.QueueBuildAsync(build);
```

And that works! The template parameters are passed to Azure DevOps and are used in the build.

Answer (score 0):

Why `Parameters` is not a correct parameter? For example, you may use this:

```
    private static Build QueueBuild(string TeamProjectName, int BuildDefId)
    {
        var buildDefinition = BuildClient.GetDefinitionAsync(TeamProjectName, BuildDefId).Result;
        var teamProject = ProjectClient.GetProject(TeamProjectName).Result;
        return BuildClient.QueueBuildAsync(new Build() { Definition = buildDefinition, Project = teamProject, Parameters = "{\"my.var1\":  \"MY_VAR1\", \"my.var2\":  \"MY_VAR2\"}" }).Result;
    }
```

The result will be like here:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the problem is: These are variables, not parameters. I needed to set parameters that where defined in my YAML files. And this doesn't do that unfortunately.